# Website showing relative links without the server name

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

My website in .net Framework 4 on classic ASP.NET. When I run it on my machine it shows all links in the menu bar as relative links but without the server name so I cannot navigate to any of them. OR when I click on any link, I then have to manually type in `http://servername` or `localhost` to make it work.

I have checked everywhere `~` has been used in menu bar. It is working on other machines. Just on my machine, it is showing in a weird way.

tried in different vs versions VS 2019, VS 2013 web both showing error

Comment: I just tried in VS 2012 , it is working properly. however i want to know why it is not working in VS 2013 and VS 2019 ....everything else is same.
All other users were using vs 2012

Comment: OR how do i upgrade the website to VS 2013 and higher without changing the .net framework version ?